# SQL Server 2008 cannot load Microsoft.SqlServer.Types

Tags: sql, sql-server, .net-assembly, spatial

After a restart of the database server,  SQL Server 2008 cannot load Microsoft.SqlServer.Types any more.

A simple query:

```
declare @point geometry = geometry::Point(10,10, 3006)
select @point
```

Gets this error message:

> Msg 10314, Level 16, State 14, Line 1
>   An error occurred in the Microsoft .NET Framework while trying to load assembly id 1. The server may be running out of resources, or the assembly may not be trusted with PERMISSION_SET = EXTERNAL_ACCESS or UNSAFE. Run the query again, or check documentation to see how to solve the assembly trust issues. For more information about this error:
>
> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'microsoft.sqlserver.types, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 
>      at System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection)
>
> at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
>
> at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
>
> at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)

The spatial functions worked fine just before the restart, and no other known changes has been done to the server.

The assembly seems to be in the GAC and on the right place under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies`

What could be the problem?

Thanks in advance

/Tommy